# Unable to start apache

Tags: macos, apache, ssl, configuration, lets-encrypt

I've trying to start httpd 2.4 on OSX with SSL installed from

```
brew install httpd24 --with-privileged-ports
```

and I'm trying to start it with an SSL certificate generated from letsencrypt. However, it's not starting. I've upped the log levels to see if they help. The error.log has

```
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256058 2016] [ssl:trace3] [pid 39588] ssl_engine_init.c(506): Creating new SSL context (protocols: TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2)
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256159 2016] [ssl:trace1] [pid 39588] ssl_engine_init.c(768): Configuring permitted SSL ciphers [ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP]
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256340 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 39588] ssl_engine_init.c(949): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256345 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 39588] ssl_engine_init.c(412): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256482 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 39588] AH02566: Unable to retrieve certificate www.myserver.com:443:0
```

and the ssl_engine.log has

```
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256029 2016] [ssl:trace2] [pid 39588] ssl_engine_rand.c(125): Init: Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256050 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 39588] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I've got openssl installed via homebrew as well as the openssl on OSX (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016). 
and the output from the libexec in httpd24/2.4.23_2

```
otool -L mod_ssl.so

mod_ssl.so:
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

which I've checked is there and is in 1.0.2j version.

The output from

```
sudo apachectl configtest

Syntax OK
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to restart in the end.

Somehow I had commented out the

```
Listen 443
```

so it wasn't listening on 443, which I guess was what it was trying to tell me with

```
Thu Oct 06 21:33:18.256482 2016] [ssl:error] [pid 39588] AH02566: Unable to retrieve certificate www.myserver.com:443:0
```

Comment: as well as that it looks like brew with openssl 1.0.2j doesn't play nicely with the ssl certs from letsencrypt. If I install from macports then I can load the certificates. That seems to use openssl 1.0.2h.